# Sum of Rule for runtime calculation doesn't hold true for one case... am I doing it right?

Tags: algorithm

Rule of sum as stated indicates that for T1 of O(f(n)) and T2 of O(g(n), T1 + T2 is of O(max (f, g)). This associative property of addition extends this to any number of Ti's.

T1 + T2 + ... + Tn is O(max(f1, f2, f3, ...., fn)) fi's being corresponding runtime order for Ti's.

But consider a situation where f1, f2, f3,..., fn follows a arithmetic progression, i.e.

T1 --> O(1.n), (1 multiplied by n)
T2 --> O(2.n),
...
Tn --> O(n.n)

From rule of sum, max(f1, f2, .., fn) would lead to the answer O(n^2)
But, if you add up T1 + T2 + ... + T2 <= O(n^2.(n+1)/2)

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is a more complicated version of:
given 
`f1, f2, ..., fn` where `Ti=1` and thus `O(max(fi)) = 1`, instead of `n` (which is the correct answer)

The reason is you don't want the number of summed element to depend on n.

```
f1+...+fk (k constant, ok -> O(max(fi)))
f1+...+f_(n-k) (k constant, ko, O((n-k)max(fi))=O(n*max(fi))
```

Comment: ohkay, yeah its blunder. No. of summed elements need not be same as the input side N. my bad. Sorry about super duper late reply, not used to stackoverflow usage a lot.